# Access Token returned by AWS cognito hosted UI and pre built UI are different

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have built Angular application using AWS Amplify and Cognito user pool. I'am able to successfully login and access my homepage. However, when I check the access token ( see image 1 )
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X209S.png)

1. **Amplify Pre built UI**
   When I try to use this access token to validate my api with API gateway i get unauthorized error. I have added the correct Cognito user pool in API gateway
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIcLF.png)
2. **Hosted UI URL**
   When I access the hosted UI with below url

https://xxxxxxxxx.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?&client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&response_type=token&scope=aws.cognito.signin.user.admin+email+openid+phone+profile&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fadmin%2Fhome

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hJ1z.png)

I am successfully login

http://localhost:4200/admin/home#id_token=<ID_TOKEN>&access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>&expires_in=3600&token_type=Bearer

with the ACCES_TOKEN I am able to authenicate the API gateway.

The Cognito user pool was automatically created by the command : amplify add auth.

I searched on google and found that I have to add the following grant types and connect scopes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seCNE.png)

But, still I am unable to figure out how to get the same access token through Pre Built UT as hosted UI

@Ankush - After you suggestion, I updated the auth config. Here is my aws auth configuration

```
const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "us-east-1",
    "aws_cognito_identity_pool_id": "us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxXXXx",
    "aws_cognito_region": "us-east-1",
    "aws_user_pools_id": "us-east-1_XXXXXX",
    "aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "48XxXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxd",
    "oauth": {
        "domain": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-dev.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com",
        "scope": [
            "phone",
            "email",
            "openid",
            "profile",
            "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"
        ],
        "redirectSignIn": "http://localhost:4200/admin/home/",
        "redirectSignOut": "http://localhost:4200/",
        "responseType": "token"
    },
    "federationTarget": "COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
    "aws_cognito_username_attributes": [],
    "aws_cognito_social_providers": [],
    "aws_cognito_signup_attributes": [
        "EMAIL"
    ],
    "aws_cognito_mfa_configuration": "OFF",
    "aws_cognito_mfa_types": [
        "SMS"
    ],
    "aws_cognito_password_protection_settings": {
        "passwordPolicyMinLength": 8,
        "passwordPolicyCharacters": []
    },
    "aws_cognito_verification_mechanisms": [
        "EMAIL"
    ]
};
```

The URL generated after updating the oauth [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoXE1.png) I am getting the hosted UI URL and its returning me the correct URL ( means if I use the access token from URL,the api gateway is getting authenticated). But the access token mentioned in the local storage is different ( my application fetch this access token mentioned in storage token)
Why both are different ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoXE1.png)

here is my code snippet ( which picks the local storage access token )

**cognito.service.ts**

const POOL_DATA = {
UserPoolId : "us-east-1_Si3XXXX5",
ClientId:"48sXXXXXXXXXXXXvdt8g5ad"
}

const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(POOL_DATA);

getAuthenticatedUser() {

```
return userPool.getCurrentUser();
```

}

**Candidate.service.ts**

getCandidates(): Observable {

```
this.cognitoService.getAuthenticatedUser()?.getSession((err:any, session:any) =>{
  if(err)
  {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    this.httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
       
        Authorization : session.getAccessToken().getJwtToken(),
        
      }),
    };     
  }
  
} )
return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`, this.httpOptions);
```

}

Comment: When using Amplify UI, how are you obtaining the access token and sending it? Can you add the piece of code in the question. Also, try sending ID Token as a bearer token, that might work.